# Deployment preview with ephemeral PostgreSQL

Tags: django, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

My architecture currently consists of a webapp built with Django and Webpack and deployed on Cloud Run. The build process consists of just a Dockerfile.

When someone from my team opens a new PR, we would like for deployment to commence automatically to a new instance. This is explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/configure-deployment-previews) (deployment previews). However, I would like for an ephemeral database to also be spawn - similarly to what happens in [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps). This is necessary because otherwise conflicting Django's migrations may damage Stage's database (e.g., both me and a teammate pushing two conflicting migrations).